# NullPointerException when adding objects to JPanel

Tags: nullpointerexception

I get a NullPointerException when I run my program:

```
        JPanel[] myPanel = new JPanel[totalTests];
    JTextField [] mytextfield = new JTextField[totalTests];
    JComboBox[] myCombo       = new JComboBox[totalTests];
    JCheckBox[] myNotReturn   = new JCheckBox[totalTests];
    JCheckBox[] myNotEval     = new JCheckBox[totalTests];

    jLabelTestcount.setText(Integer.toString(totalTests));
    jLabelToberesulted.setText(Integer.toString(totalTests));


    for (int tst=0; tst< TestSetList.size(); tst++){

      switch (TestSetList.get(tst).getTestSetup()){
        case "TEXT" : {     

           myPanel[tst] = new JPanel();
           myPanel[tst].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));
           myPanel[tst].setSize(120, 60);
           myPanel[tst].setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
           myPanel[tst].setVisible(true);
           jPanelTests.add(myPanel[tst]);
          mytextfield[tst].setSize(10, 10);
          myNotReturn[tst].setName("No Return");
          myNotEval[tst].setName("Not Evauated");

        JLabel testName = new JLabel(TestSetList.get(tst).getTestDesctiption());

        myPanel[tst].add(testName);
        myPanel[tst].add(mytextfield[tst]);
        myPanel[tst].add(myNotReturn[tst]);
        myPanel[tst].add(myNotEval[tst]);
        myPanel[tst].add(myCombo[tst]);
```

Please help. The JPanel is added without an error but when I set the size for the JTextfield then I get the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your answer in your question itself. You are getting NullPointerException at your JTextField while setting your size to respective component. It means you haven't initialized you JTextField before setting its size.

### Add

> mytextfield[tst] = new JTextField();
> myNotReturn[tst]   = new JCheckBox();
> myNotEval[tst]     = new JCheckBox();

## Solution is:

```
    JPanel[] myPanel = new JPanel[totalTests];
    JTextField [] mytextfield = new JTextField[totalTests];
    JComboBox[] myCombo       = new JComboBox[totalTests];
    JCheckBox[] myNotReturn   = new JCheckBox[totalTests];
    JCheckBox[] myNotEval     = new JCheckBox[totalTests];

    jLabelTestcount.setText(Integer.toString(totalTests));
    jLabelToberesulted.setText(Integer.toString(totalTests));


for (int tst=0; tst< TestSetList.size(); tst++){

  switch (TestSetList.get(tst).getTestSetup()){
    case "TEXT" : {     

       myPanel[tst] = new JPanel();
       myPanel[tst].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));
       myPanel[tst].setSize(120, 60);
       myPanel[tst].setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
       myPanel[tst].setVisible(true);
       jPanelTests.add(myPanel[tst]);

      mytextfield[tst] = new JTextField();
      mytextfield[tst].setSize(10, 10);

      myNotReturn[tst]   = new JCheckBox();
      myNotReturn[tst].setName("No Return");

      myNotEval[tst] = new JCheckBox();
      myNotEval[tst].setName("Not Evauated");

    JLabel testName = new JLabel(TestSetList.get(tst).getTestDesctiption());

    myPanel[tst].add(testName);
    myPanel[tst].add(mytextfield[tst]);
    myPanel[tst].add(myNotReturn[tst]);
    myPanel[tst].add(myNotEval[tst]);
    myPanel[tst].add(myCombo[tst]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`new JTextField[totalTests]` only constructs an *array* that can hold `JTextField` instances, but your code never actually constructs any `JTextField` instances. Therefore, `mytextfield[tst]` will always be `null`.

Now, with respect to `myPanel[tst]`, your code *does* do the right thing -- it constructs a new `JPanel` and assigns it to `myPanel[tst]` *before* it attempts to dereference that array element.

You need to do a similar thing before you attempt to dereference `mytextfield[tst]`. For example:

```
mytextfield[tst] = new JTextField();
mytextfield[tst].setSize(10, 10);
...
```

You have similar issues with the JComboBox and JCheckBox arrays.